# Telegram bot to recognize URLs

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, message-handlers

I'm creating my first Telegram bot. I want the bot to filter text looking only for URLs, and trigger when is found.

For example, if someone types in the chat "www.google.com", I want the bot to recognize it as a URL and later do X action. I tried filtering for words to get an exact URL, but I'm doing it wrong.

I'm trying with `Filters.entity(URL)` but I've not been able to make the full necessary code.

This is the actual bot code:

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, ConversationHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import os
import random
import requests

TOKEN = "XXXXX"
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))
updater = Updater(TOKEN)

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                   level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
   """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
   update.message.reply_text('Hi!')

def coin(update, context):
   ''' ⚪️/⚫️ Moneda 
   Genera un número elatorio entre 1 y 2.
   '''
   cid=update.message.chat_id
   msg="⚫️ Cara" if random.randint(1,2)==1 else "⚪️ Cruz"
   # Responde directametne en el canal donde se le ha hablado.
   update.message.reply_text(msg)

def help(update, context):
   """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
   update.message.reply_text('Help!')

def links(update, context):
   """Echo the user message."""
   url = str(update.message.text)
   if url.lower() == '*morning*':
   update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)
   
def error(update, context):
   """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
   logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

def main():
   """Start the bot."""
   # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
   # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
   # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
   updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

   # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
   dp = updater.dispatcher

   # on different commands - answer in Telegram
   dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
   dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
   dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("coin", coin))          

   # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram    
   dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.entity(URL), links))

   # log all errors
   dp.add_error_handler(error)

   # Start the Bot
   updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                         port=PORT,
                         url_path=TOKEN,
webhook_url="XXXXX/" + TOKEN)

   # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
   # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
   # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
   updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: After reading the docs, it's not clear to me if messages with the URL entity are messages that *contain* URLs or the entire message is a URL. It's possible there is some confusion there. Secondly, in your `links` function, the message text can never be `*morning*` because that isn't a valid URL. That message would not trigger that handler. Try just spitting the message back unmodified, that will show you what is getting detected as a URL message.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to filter the URL to avoid the bot trigger with all the written URL. But was a mistake, because I need first to make it works reading all URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.entity(URL), links))
```

change this to
this ->

```
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.entity('url'), links))
```

disable your other replyto normal text handler .. because that function concider your links as a normal text

Comment: `Filters.entity('url')` — this comment saved my time! Everywhere is shown URL in examples — and what variable URL is equal to — no any explanations...